# JavaScript: Merge Two Lists into JSON object and append same key values together without ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays

A quick javascript question. Given two arrays and assuming that they are the same length. I would like to combine the two arrays into an array of json objects. ALSO if the code is already present in the array then append the error to the existing .error element. If anyone could provide a solution that uses vanilla javascript and NOT ES6 it would be appreciated.

```
var codes = ["12345", "12345","67890", "67890", "67890","67890","12092", "12092"];

var errors = ["12345 error 1","12345 error 2","67890 error 1","67890 error 2","67890 error 3","67890 error 4","12092 error 1","12092 error 2"];
```

Should be transformed to

```
{
    "code": "12345",
    "error": "12345 error 1, 12345 error 2"
},
{
    "code": "67890",
    "error": "67890 error 1, 67890 error 2, 67890 error 3, 67890 error 4, 67890 error 5"
},
{
    "code": "12092",
    "error": "12092 error 1 , 12092 error 2"
}
```

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: I was struggling to come up with one. The version of Javascript that im using doesnt use ES6. So im actually at a loss where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them using map, then group them and convert that to an array of objects then

```js
const codes = ["12345", "12345","67890", "67890", "67890","67890","12092", "12092"];
const errors = ["12345 error 1","12345 error 2","67890 error 1","67890 error 2","67890 error 3","67890 error 4","12092 error 1", "12092 error 2"];

const res = Array.from(
    codes.map((e, i) => ({code: e, errors: errors[i]}))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.set(b.code, (a.get(b.code) || []).concat(b.errors)), new Map))
    .map(([k, v]) => ({code:k, errors: v}));
console.log(res);
```

If you really want the errors to be a single string, add .join()

```
.map(([k, v]) => ({code:k, errors: v.join()}));
```

---

Pre ES6 Version

```js
var codes = ["12345", "12345", "67890", "67890", "67890", "67890", "12092", "12092"];
var errors = ["12345 error 1", "12345 error 2", "67890 error 1", "67890 error 2", "67890 error 3", "67890 error 4", "12092 error 1", "12092 error 2"];

var grouped =
  codes.map(function(e, i) {
    return {
      code: e,
      errors: errors[i]
    };
  })
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    a[b.code] = (a[b.code] || []).concat(b.errors);
    return a;
  }, {});

var res = Object.keys(grouped).map(function(e) {
  return {
    code: e,
    errors: grouped[e]
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is correct. But after further research ive discovered the version of JavaScript that im using does not support ES6. So functions like map and Array.from cant be used. I've updated the question with this information.

Comment: Added a version that doesn't use es6. Please make sure to include all necessary information into your question the next time @NickTheDev